# Processing delimiter within a field in a csv file using Scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, delimiter

I've got a .csv file with | delimiter and the following command fits me, exept for some records which contain delimiter inside a name of an artist

```
val df_artist = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").option("delimiter", "|").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").load("./artists.csv");
```

ordinary:

```
ARVYNKF1272BA83168|TRAGGZG128F92F9B5E|Black Devil Disco Club
```

irregular:

```
ARQJXPL1187B9B4D6B|TRWUJAE128F92E3E7D|M|A|R|R|S
ARZCIDG1187B992CE3||Kid Creole | The Coconuts
```

is it possible to make first two columns and everything what will be left put to third column, ignoring delimiters?

I use Spark 2.1.1, if it is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use `sparkContext` `textFile` to read the `csv` file and `split` the line with `|` delimiter and choose first two strings as first two columns and the rest as the third column. The working code for this is

```
val data = sc.textFile("./artists.csv")
data.map(line => line.split("\\|"))
  .map(array => (array(0), array(1), array.drop(2)))
  .toDF("rowId", "ticketId", "movies")
  .show(false)
```

Given, the input file contains data as

```
ARVYNKF1272BA83168|TRAGGZG128F92F9B5E|Black Devil Disco Club
ARQJXPL1187B9B4D6B|TRWUJAE128F92E3E7D|M|A|R|R|S
ARZCIDG1187B992CE3||Kid Creole | The Coconuts
```

Output of above code would be

```
+------------------+------------------+----------------------------+
|rowId             |ticketId          |movies                      |
+------------------+------------------+----------------------------+
|ARVYNKF1272BA83168|TRAGGZG128F92F9B5E|[Black Devil Disco Club]    |
|ARQJXPL1187B9B4D6B|TRWUJAE128F92E3E7D|[M, A, R, R, S]             |
|ARZCIDG1187B992CE3|                  |[Kid Creole ,  The Coconuts]|
+------------------+------------------+----------------------------+
```